# Determine $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) / \mathbb{Q})$ where $\alpha = \omega + \omega^7 + \omega^{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose $\alpha = \omega + \omega^7 + \omega^{11}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive root of unity of order 19. Determine the Galois group of
$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) / \mathbb{Q}$. With which other well known group is 
$\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) / \mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic?

My own work: Since $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. It holds that
$19=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]$. Since 19 is a prime number and 
$ [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]  \neq 1$ it holds that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]=19$. The only group of order 19 is $\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z}$.

Is this a correct answer? Is there a way to solve this question using less theory? Thanks!

Comment: The Galois group of $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ is $(\mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z)^\times$, which is cyclic of order 18, not 19.

Comment: Could you explain me why?

Comment: The element $\omega$ can be sent to any other primitive $19$th root of unity. There are 18 of these.

Comment: So I just need to show that if $\tau(\alpha) = \omega^n$ with $n=1...18$ can work as a group morphism?

Comment: The automorphisms of $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ are $\omega \mapsto \omega^a$, for $a$ relatively prime to 19. Your element $\alpha$ is the trace of $\omega$ under the action of the automorphism $\omega \mapsto \omega^{11}$, so $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ which is fixed by $\omega \mapsto \omega^{11}$. This automorphism has order 3.

Comment: Ok, so if anything it involves more theory... Thank you

Comment: To find a solution try thinking about the main theorems of Galois theory to solve this problem. The subfield $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ will correspond to one of the subgroups of $\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z18$. These are the cyclic groups of order dividing 18.

Comment: I have a new question for you actually. I thought $\text{Gal}(E/K)$ was supposed to be a divisor of $[E : K]$. Is my statement that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]=19$ wrong and why?

Comment: If $\omega$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, then the minimal polynomial for $\omega$ is the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial, which is irreducible of degree $\varphi(n)$. Here $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. In this case, $[\mathbb Q(\omega) : \mathbb Q] = \varphi(19) = 18$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I sort of misunderstood the question there...